# How bad is 30% cylinder leak?

Tags: leak, cylinder

I recently performed a cylinder leakdown test searching for a cause for oil loss. On 5/6 cylinders, I pumped it up to 90 psi on the left gauge and the right gauge was between 75-80. Only 1/6 wouldn't go past 65. I put my hand on the intake for that cylinder on the plenum and didn't notice and leaks, then put my hand on the exhaust pipe and there was maybe a very low flow. The air may have been going past the cylinder rings and into the crankcase but I'm not sure how to check that.

How bad is a 30% leak, especially if it's on the exhaust side ?

Comment: You check airflow into the crankcase by pulling the oil filler cap.

Comment: and you're sure the exhaust valves were closed?

Comment: If they weren't closed, I'd be getting 0. I did the test on that one multiple times

Comment: 30% indicates a problem. how is compression and engine vacuum?

Comment: @Moab  Put your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

"put my hand on the exhaust pipe and there was maybe a very low flow."

You have found your problem, there should be 0 flow.

Comment: Additionally this sounds like a possible bent, or burn valve or valve seat. Recommend taking a look inside of the cylinder with a borescope if possible. I'd hazard that there's carbon build up on the valve  preventing effective sealing. Anything short of taking the head off would be guessing.